# How to retrieve and Showing OutPut String from "EditText" or "Toast"

Tags: android, md5, android-toast

i used below link, for Computing Md5 Hashes.(Convert String to MD5 Hash),

```
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml
```

and with this :

```
try { 
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, AeSimpleMD5.MD5(rawString), 2000).show();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

i can see MD5 hash with Toast.

actually, i have `one button` and 2 `Edittext` and when user inputed string on first `EditText`, user with button can see `MD5` result with this Toast.

but,
i need Instead of Toast, its showing in EditText2.
edit : also i can with below code retrieve Input First `TextEdit` with button and showing that in TextEdit2 :

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
String myString = String;
et.setText(myString);
```

but i need output result put on this.

any Ideas?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: just use EditText2.setText(AeSimpleMD5.MD5(rawString));

Comment: thank you guys,its done with this : `EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                 editText2.setText(AeSimpleMD5.MD5(rawString));`

Answer (score 1):

To get the text from textView use

```
textView.getText();
```

as this method returns Text so you should do like this to get it as String type

```
String value = textView.getText().toString();
```

Further, To set a string in textView use

```
textView.setText(yourStringObject);
```

For your MD5 use

```
textView.setText(AeSimpleMD5.MD5(rawString));
```

To implement onClick on button make a anonymous class using onClickListner
like this

```
View name = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        /**  onClick Listener for name**/
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Handle view click here

                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the MD5 value in a string
then just write this

```
ed_myEdittext2.setText(string);
```

ed_myEdittext2 your 2nd editText
string is your stored MD5 value.

Answer (score 0):

In the button's onClick method, the following will set the MD5 Hash to the second edit text:

```
editText2.setText(AeSimpleMD5.MD5(rawString));
```

Make sure you have inflated the EditText's view from your xml, e.g.:

```
EditText editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text2_id);
```